# How to fetch data from google sheet in next app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-sheets, next.js, fetch

I'm trying google sheet as a mini database with the nextJs app but how to use getStaticPaths to get specific page data.
in this app I'm not using google sheet API I'm getting data as JSON.

```js
export const getStaticPaths = async () => {
    const res = await fetch('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OgT7pYpT__3y1qgC6Nlb8dE759drBFTSWN3H0g5M_Ps/gviz/tq?tqx=out:json')
    const text = await res.text();
    const data = await JSON.parse(text.substr(47).slice(0, -2));

    const paths = data.table.rows.map((table) => {
        return {
            params: {
                title: table.c[1].v
            }
        }
    })

    return {
        paths,
        fallback: false
    }
}

export const getStaticProps = async (context) => {
    const title = context.params.title;
    const res = await fetch('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OgT7pYpT__3y1qgC6Nlb8dE759drBFTSWN3H0g5M_Ps/gviz/tq?tqx=out:json')

    const text = await res.text();
    const data = await JSON.parse(text.substr(47).slice(0, -2));

    return {
        props: { posts: data }
    }
}

const Title = ({ posts }) => {
    return (
        <>
            <div>
                <h1>{ posts.table.rows[0].c[0].v }</h1>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default Title;
```

how to get data in dynamic page from google sheet.

Comment: sorry, i delte my answer, i have not noticed that you use nextjs